# Migrating Postgis database from one desktop to another fails with backup and restore feature

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I've received multiple backup files from databases which are present on a localhost server from another desktop (not mine). I'm trying to import the databases on my own localhost environment with the restore function. The host server operates on postgresql 11 while my own dekstop has postgresql 13. Whilst very simple new 'testing' databases which only include a schema and one table are imported whithout problems, there is one backup which does not restore via pgadmin 4. The restoration process immeadiatly halts after a few seconds and gives error: *Failed (Exit code 1)*. The database which does not restore has a postgis extension.

I've thus tried smaller and newer databases which restore without problems. I've tinkered with the restore options: not saving the owner, cleaning before restore, only trying to import data and so on.
I've also received an entire database backup, not only the schema I needed. However, this also returns the same error and problem.
Solutions I have found online almost all say to ignore this problem, but no data gets restored and as such I cannot ignore it.

Any tips or possible solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth checking the logs to see if there is a specific error that is causing the restore to fail.